# How to disable all navigation from webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to conduct a online quiz competition for an event, I have disabled the user from selecting text, images etc. 
But now important thing I need is to disable navigation. User should not be able to navigate to other window, or even can not open any other program for help until the quiz ends.
This page is created using HTML, PHP and Java Script.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not possible, sorry.

Comment: Do you just want to disable all links?

Comment: Do you control the client machines people will be taking the quiz's on? If not, you are putting together an *extremely* naive solution that won't work for many users.

Comment: _can not open any other program_ - this is a non starter. t's just not possible to impose this. In any case, there's nothing stopping the participant using another device.

Comment: And there's nothing at all you can do to prevent someone from opening another program from a website.

Comment: @JohnV. "Sorry"? Don't you mean, "Thank heavens"? ;)

Comment: Actually the purpose is, user should not google the answer using same browser, I have seen some exams where they disable creating new window or tab of browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website is handled by the browser. No browser will allow you to access the desktop to this extent and put restrictions like this. Generally for such things, websites keep time limit. Since the websites cant control if the user refers somewhere else, they can control how much time you take to answer each question. You can set a time such that they may not get enough time to refer. Also you need to make sure that handling the time is fully done from php not js. Php can have a session variable to save the time when the question is request and when the answer is submitted, the php code can check how much time the user has taken. If you try from js it maybe easier by can be edited from the user.

If you still want to stop the user from using any other application, you need to create a software not a website.